# How is this integral over a triangle be changed to a single integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

In a paper I'm reading, the following equality is shown $$\int_0^h \int_0^x f(t+x) - f(t+y) dy\ dx = 2 \int_0^h f(t+x)(x-h/2) dx. $$ I can show that they are equal for a specific choice for the function $f(t)$, but I cannot see why it would be true in general. What is the proof for an unknown function $f(t)$?

Comment: Consider the terms of subtraction  individually and pay attention to the integration variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comment for first term we have
$$\int_\limits0^h \int_\limits 0^x f(t+x)  dy\ dx =\int_\limits0^h xf(t+x)dx$$
Hope you can finish with second.

Comment: I didn't realize that I should change the order of integration in the second term until your comment. Thanks!